# Filter out a specific character from string. Only want to remove it if it appears to the left of certain characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to filter out a character from a string. The catch is that I'm only trying to remove it if it appears to the left of certain characters. For example in this one trying to turn the string 'abcdarjakffa'  into 'bcdrjakffa'. In this hypothetical case I want to remove all the occurrences of 'a' if they directly precede 'b' or 'r'.

Watching regex tutorials now and it makes sense. The issue is how can I get it to remove it for only these conditional cases.

If anyone can point me to either the solution or a tutorial that can help me find the solution I'd greatly appreciate it :slight_smile:

Comment: Please add the code of, what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) for the letters `b` or `r` with a quantifier of 1 and then use this captured group in your replacement:

```js
const str = "abcdarjakffa";
const result = str.replace(/a([b|r]{1})/g, '$1')

console.log(result); // logs bcdrjakffa
```